# JMS lookup inside thread fails

Tags: java, jboss, jms, java-threads

I have my client trying to lookup a JMS server. Here is my class `JmsTest.java`:

```java
public static void main(String[] aInArgs)
{
    boolean bContinue = true;

    try
    {
        // determine JmsTest configuration based on command line arguments.
        JmsTest jmsTest = parseCommandLine(aInArgs);

        // connect to the server.
        //jmsTest.initializeConnection();
        Thread jmsFaultClientThread = null;
        
        jmsFaultClientThread = new Thread("RUN") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("jmsFaultClient starting...");
                    jmsTest.initializeConnection();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
                }
                System.out.println("jmsFaultClient started.");
            }
        };
        jmsFaultClientThread.start();
```

And my method `initializeConnection()`:

```java
public void initializeConnection() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user );
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);

        System.out.println("Initializing Topic (" + strName + ")...");
        try
        {
            topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            topicConnectionFactory = getExternalFactory(jndiContext);
        }
```

When I run `jmsTest.initializeConnection()` like this everything works, and the lookup is working. However, the problem is when it's run inside the thread it gets stuck without any exception or any error. It's just stuck.

In my logs i'm seeing:

```java
System.out.println("Initializing Topic (" + strName + ")...");
```

Which is a log inside my try / catch, and nothing else.

In dependencies, I have 2 jars, contening **javax\jms**.  With the first one it's work inside the thread, and with the second one it doesn't. But I don't know why my jar can "block" the thread.

UPDATE 1 :

@AnotherJavaprogrammer said me to print the error:

here is my lookup with print :

```java
try
{
    getLogger().debug("TRY context");
    Context lInitialContext = (Context) jndiContext.lookup(JMS_CONTEXT);
    lInitialContext.lookup("SAMConnectionFactory");
    getLogger().debug("END trying context");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    getLogger().debug("Catch");
    getLogger().debug("Exception", e);
}
```

The output from `getLogger().debug("END trying context")` never comes, and I don't see the `getLogger().debug("Catch")` one either. So it appears I'm really "stuck" inside the `lookup()`. I can't go further, and it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Print the exception in the catch clause to see what happened.

Comment: yes, i would to print the exception. But i can't ...
Check my update.
No exceptions are raised, and i can't see logs after .lookup().

It seems, that i'm really stuck/ blocked inside lookup() without any actions

Comment: Take a thread dump, and post it to the question. That will show exactly where your thread is stuck.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you get a thread dump?

Comment: So your main thread just exits and because your inner RUN thread is not Daemon it hangs there. That might be the issue? Try join or Thread.sleep(20000) after start()

Comment: Yeah, i found the solution. In fact, that wasn't due to thread. 
I launched my application with jdb to get the thread dump and i realized that i got a new error. And this error wasn't caught by the thread.

The problem was inside the jar, i had a dependency org.apache.commons.beanutils, that i haved already include in my project.
2 same dependencies was the root cause.

I found the duplicated library with tattletale.

thanks guys !